# Commas around both sides of prepositional phrase?

Tags: commas, prepositional-phrases

I'm not sure what to call this sort of prepositional phrase, but this sort seems to interrupt the thought to add clarification. I almost want to call it an interjectional prepositional phrase.

Some examples:

- Are we not in principle taking a risk?
- Are we not, in principle, taking a risk?
- You in full knowledge allow discrimination to go unquestioned.
- You, in full knowledge, allow discrimination to go unquestioned.

So is it permissible and/or preferable to use commas in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take is that this is a [nonrestrictive clause](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/comma-with-nonrestrictive-clauses/). If used as a nonrestrictive clause, the commas would be necessary in both of your examples.